# What is pythonic way to get list's value's increment list?

Tags: python

What is pythonic way to get list's value's  increment list? I want to reduce code lines.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> sum = 0
>>> sum_list = []
>>> for i in l:
...     sum += i
...     sum_list.append(sum)
...
>>> sum_list
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

Comment: On Python 3: `list(itertools.accumulate(l))`.

Comment: or `print([sum(l[0:i]) for i in l])` without using itertools